# Reading text from multiple text files at the same time and splitting them into array of words

Tags: matlab

I want help in reading all the text files at the same time and also splitting the text to be stored into an array. I have tried for this but was not able to do so. The main problem occurring is that even while using `for` loop for reading text file the `strsplit` splits only one text file. How can i split all of them at once into different arrays, means one array for one text file.
Below is the code so far-

```
for i = 1:10
file = [num2str(i) '.eng'];
% load string from a file

STR = importdata(file);

% extract string between tags
B = regexprep(STR, '<.*?>','');

% split each string by delimiters and add to C
C = [];
for j=1:length(B)
    if ~isempty(B{j})
        C = [C strsplit(B{j}, {'/', ' '})];
    end
end
```

Below is sample of text file---

`<DOC>`

`<DOCNO>annotations/01/1515.eng</DOCNO>`

`<TITLE>Yacare Ibera</TITLE>`

`<DESCRIPTION>an alligator in the water;</DESCRIPTION>`

`<NOTES></NOTES>`

`<LOCATION>Corrientes, Argentina</LOCATION>`

`<DATE>August 2002</DATE>`

`<IMAGE>images/01/1515.jpg</IMAGE>`

`<THUMBNAIL>thumbnails/01/1515.jpg</THUMBNAIL>`

`</DOC>`

Comment: Do you have some code that exhibits the problematic behaviour?

Comment: Should be `file = [num2str(i) '.eng'];` ?

Comment: And better use `j` for your second loop. I forget the specific scope rule that MatLab follows because I avoid using the same name for for-loop counters, especially nested ones.

Comment: the files are from 1.eng to 10.eng.

Comment: i corrected as you indicated, but it still reads only file 10.eng, that is the last file of the loop

Comment: Is it in `C` that you save the string? Then you may want to define it before the first loop so you do not overwrite it for every file `i.eng`:)

Comment: Thank you Sir, but the next problem is how to find which word appears in which text file. Like word `Alligator` is in which text file.

Comment: Have you inspected the output of the code? It seems to me that the `regexprep` replaces everything between the angle brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you are looking for the word "alligator". Then you could do the following

```
clc

word = 'alligator';

num_of_files = 10;

C = cell(num_of_files, 1);

for i = 1:10

    file = [num2str(i) '.eng'];
    %// load string from a file
    STR = importdata(file);

    %// extract string between tags
    %// assuming you want to remove the angle brackets
    B = regexprep(STR, '<.*?>','');
    B(strcmp(B, '')) = [];

    %// split each string by delimiters and add to C    

    tmp = regexp(B, '/| ', 'split');
    C{i} = [tmp{:}];

end

where = [];

for j = 1:length(C)

    if find(strcmp(C{j}, word))

        where = [where num2str(j) '.eng, '];

    end

end

if length(where) == 0

    disp(['No file contains the word ' word '.'])

else

    where(end-1:end) = [];
    disp(['The word ' word ' is contained in: ' where])

end
```

Because I used 10 copies of your file, the word "alligator" is in each one of them so I get

> The word alligator is contained in: 1.eng, 2.eng, 3.eng, 4.eng, 5.eng,
>   6.eng, 7.eng, 8.eng, 9.eng, 10.eng

Whereas, if I set `word = 'cohomology'`, the output is

> No file contains the word cohomology.

Comment: Sir, where to give the words to match with text in files.

Comment: You would like to manually type a word and find out in which file it was?

Comment: this error is coming---  Error using cell/ismember>cellismemberR2012a (line 199)
Input A of class cell and input B of class cell must be cell arrays of strings, unless one is a
string.

Error in cell/ismember (line 71)
    [varargout{1:nlhs}] = cellismemberR2012a(varargin{:});

Comment: Try replacing `ismember` with `strcmp`, as I did. It is hard to debug the code without knowing anything about the input files. I am sure there are cases that elude my imagination; I used the code, above, on some dummy files without errors. If you can upload some sample files, perhaps I could be of more help.

Comment: i posted the sample for text file in my question.

Comment: when i replaced `ismember` with `strcmp`, all 10 files are coming as output

Comment: Is this desired behaviour?

Comment: No, i want only the file in which the word matches.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Now i will try to modify to work it with `ismember`

Comment: Can you tell me how to display output as `i.jpg` instead of just `i`

Comment: Sir i needed the extension to open those text files, but this modification only saves the name and cant help in opening those text files.